# Oracle 11g Database NUMBER value with a zero at end, a bug?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table T1 in production:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    "SPECIFIC_UNCERTAINTY" NUMBER
)
```

And today I saw its content like this:

[image: number column with ZERO at end]

Row 1 & 2 has zero at end, while row 3 is a normal value. I'd like to ask under what condition would Oracle store a ZERO at end of NUMBER value like row 1 & 2???

I ask this because for row 1 & 2, if I perform some operation (like `TO_CHAR`) on it, those value appears not to be considered as NUMBER.

```
select * from v$version;
---
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
---
```

The same query from SqlPlus, row 1 & 2 are not displayed:
[image: query result from SqlPlus]

Make it more fun, here's another query:
[image: another query result from SqlPlus]

Comment: Please execute the query in Sql*Plus and share the result

Comment: Added same query, result from SqlPlus. It seems row 1 & 2 are not displayed.

Comment: Contact Oracle support, this is not expected behaviour....

Comment: Seems like SQL Developer tool is behaving in a different way. Values in your DB is perfectly saved but not displayed correctly using SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Oracle 10.1 client driver. Updated driver used by application and problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same. It worked fine for me by displaying 0.0006, 0.0004, 0.14

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in test environment. But I can find those value with tailing ZERO in my production instance. I wonder how those tailing ZERO values got into the table.